# How to inject resolved data into controller?

Tags: angularjs

I can see the RESTful service being called within loadProfile before this route is accessed....

```
$routeProvider.when('/editProfile', {
    templateUrl: '/views/user/editprofile',
    controller: 'UserCtrl',
    access: access.user,
    resolve: {
        userProfile: function(UserSvc){
            UserSvc.loadProfile(function(userProfile){ return userProfile });
        }
    }
});
```

So how do I then get that data injected into my User controller?

**UPDATE 1**:

Matt Way clued me in on how to get the resolved data injected in my controller.  However, I immediately got an error "Unknown Provider: userProfileProvider".  Based on some other similar questions, I decided to try to remove the ng-controller="UserCtrl" attribute from the view in question.  The Unknown Provider error disappeared for my /editProfile route, but then started to appear on all of the other views/routes for this controller.

**UPDATE 2**

I watched a couple videos on egghead.io and found I was able to access the promised data in the $route.  Added this to my controller and voila!

```
if($route.current.locals.userProfile){
    $scope.userProfile = $route.current.locals.userProfile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply include the resolve items name as an input to your controller function. Eg:

```
myApp.controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', 'userProfile', 
function($scope, userProfile) {
    // Controller code goes here
}]);
```

Comment: Interesting.  I've just tried that and now I'm getting an error... "Unknown provider: userProfileProvider"

Comment: Is your `routeProvider` config part of the same module as the `UserCtrl`?

Comment: Yes...

angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies', 'ngRoute', 'ngSanitize'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {...


var UserCtrl = angular.module('myApp').controller('UserCtrl', 
    ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$sanitize', '$translate', '$location', '$interval', '$timeout', '$window', '$upload', 'UserSvc', 'AuthSvc', 'MediaSvc',
    function($rootScope, $scope, $sanitize, $translate, $location, $interval, $timeout, $window, $upload, UserSvc, AuthSvc, MediaSvc) {

Answer (score 0):

Can you return the loaded profile? I think that's why you're getting the unknown provider error.

```
function (UserSvc) {
    return UserSvc.loadProfile(function(userProfile) { return userProfile });
}
```

As a side note, I saw your comment where you pasted your controller function and it looks like there are a lot of dependencies. Might be better to reduce the number of collaborators needed.